# Cannot figure out why I am getting UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception

I am trying to get the code to "except" a string for an int. - "length". When I put except ValueError, I get back "Please enter a number", but more error is added. I also added to except UnboundLocalError, but that does not seem to work. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong! Here is my code:

```
import random
import string


def RPG():
    try:
        RPG = ""
        count = 0
        length = int(
            input("How many characters would you like in your password? "))
    except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
        print("Please enter a number.")
    while count != length:
        upper = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)]
        lower = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)]
        num = [random.choice(string.digits)]
        symbol = [random.choice(string.punctuation)]
        everything = upper + lower + num + symbol
        RPG += random.choice(everything)
        count += 1
        continue
    if count == length:
        print(RPG)
# could also use string.printable for digits, letters, punct., and whitespace.


RPG()
```

Here is what I got back from using this code and typing a string instead of an integer into length:

```
How many characters would you like in your password? j
Please enter a number.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\python\code.py", line 28, in <module>
    pwd()
  File "c:\Users\jkelly\Desktop\python\code.py", line 14, in pwd
    while count != length:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'length' referenced before assignment
```

I only expect the "Please enter a number", not the rest of the error, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the first part of your code handles and exception, then `length` never gets assigned to.

Comment: So then what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the original code is that while `count != length` always gets executed, no matter the `try-except` part. This can be avoided by only proceeding to the `while` loop if an `ValueError` or `UnboundLocalError` was not raised. By initializing `c=1` before the `try-except` and changing it to `0` only in the `try` part, the program only proceeds to the `while` loop if exception didn't happen.

```
import random
import string


def RPG():
    c=0
    try:
        RPG = ""
        count = 0
        length = int(
            input("How many characters would you like in your password? "))
    except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
        print("Please enter a number.")
        c=1
    if c==0:
        while count != length:
            upper = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)]
            lower = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)]
            num = [random.choice(string.digits)]
            symbol = [random.choice(string.punctuation)]
            everything = upper + lower + num + symbol
            RPG += random.choice(everything)
            count += 1
            continue
        if count == length:
            print(RPG)
# could also use string.printable for digits, letters, punct., and whitespace.


RPG()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cause an error, the rest of the program will still be executed. You need to repeat the input, until you get the correct input.

```
import random
import string


def RPG():
    while True:
        try:
            RPG = ""
            count = 0
            length = int(
                input("How many characters would you like in your password? "))
            break
        except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
            print("Please enter a number.")
    while count != length:
        upper = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)]
        lower = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)]
        num = [random.choice(string.digits)]
        symbol = [random.choice(string.punctuation)]
        everything = upper + lower + num + symbol
        RPG += random.choice(everything)
        count += 1
        continue
    if count == length:
        print(RPG)
# could also use string.printable for digits, letters, punct., and whitespace.


RPG()
```

Comment: I've tested it. When you input a string of letters, it prints "Please enter a number." and repeats the input request. Are you sure you've run my code?

Comment: You are correct, I did something wrong when I tried pasting; I unfortunately cannot upvote or downvote your answer because I have almost no reputation, but I hope people see this comment to know that your code is actually right. It is also a loop for if the User enters a string, so bonus! Thank you for your help.